# How to comment below the post

Tags: discussion, comments, privileges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I comment on an answer?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/362/how-do-i-comment-on-an-answer)

I really searched all the area inside the post page to comment or ask the user about the post but failed. How it is possible as many doing the same? I could see "add comment" on my posts page but not on others.

Comment: Yeah! I understood now that I need 50 privileges to comment everywhere.