# How do I add a comment to ask a question of the person so I can get more info to answer them?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I comment on an answer?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/362/how-do-i-comment-on-an-answer)

I guess it's all in the Title, but I can't find the link to just post a preliminary question , so I can get more info and then post an answer to their question.

Comment: voted. but i think this is more related to questions than answers

Comment: Only the title, which has since been generalized.