# How can I answer on a thread?

Tags: discussion

I'd like to answer on this posting here:
[How to make Logitech Anywhere MX work in Ubuntu 12.X?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/218370/how-to-make-logitech-anywhere-mx-work-in-ubuntu-12-x?answertab=votes#tab-top)

I'm logged in, but I didn't see an "Answer-Button".

Can somebody help?

Answer (score 2):

Go right to the bottom of the page, and you should see a "Your Answer" bit with a massive text box.

Write your answer in there and press the button "Post your answer" that will be right beneath your answer preview. If you decide you don't want to post, click on "discard".

Comment: @suther: to comment everywhere [you need 50 reputations](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/362/how-do-i-comment-on-a-post) but can always comment on your own post.